# Java making matrix output in correct form

Tags: java, forms, matrix, format

This is my output with `system.out.print

```
   2    22    3    4    9     25  
   6    7    8    0    10    11 `
```

What i want is:

```
   2    22    3    4    9     25  
   6    7     8    0    10    11
```

(different is 25 11 at same line for example)
How can i do this correct form?

I meant, i have 1 and 2 digits numbers so if there are 2 digits number and down is one digit, it goes to right one more up.

This is code

```
    while(i<arrangedCards.length){
        while((j<arrangedCards[i].length)&&(i*column+j<52)){
            arrangedCards[i][j]=deck.cards[i*column+j];
            System.out.print("   "
            +arrangedCards[i][j].getRank() + " ");
            j++;
        }           
        i++;
        j=0;
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Comment: Try printing tabs (`\t`) between numbers instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print accordingly

```
System.out.print("\t"+arrangedCards[i][j].getRank());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.out.printf("%2d\t",arrangedCards[i][j].getRank())`;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)

Comment: @CursedChico change `d` to `s` if you are using Strings not integers